# handling touch event with nested elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im having this problem with jquery and the layout of my html.

for example say you have a div element with id **"#test"** and a child element img with class **"nested"**

```
<div id="test">
  <img class="nested" src="example.jpg">
</div>
```

with **Jquery** I have two touch events,

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
    console.log("clicked on test id");
});

$(document).on("click", ".nested", function(){
    console.log("clicked on nested element");
});
```

my problem is on the second touch event, when the user clciked on nested item, this will also trigger the first element, because obviously its nested, and i don't want that to happen.

im pretty sure this is a simple problem, but i don't seem to get it.

Comment: [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 2):

use event.stopPropagation();

```
 $(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
    console.log("clicked on test id");
});

$(document).on("click", ".nested", function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("clicked on nested element");
});
```

reference [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the propagation with event.stopPropagation()

```
$(document).on("click", ".nested", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("clicked on nested element");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)in the Child element `click` event:

**event.stopPropagation():**

Stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
   add

```
$(document).on("click", ".nested", function(){
     event.stopPropagation()// prevents the action without notifying the parent
    console.log("clicked on nested element");
});
```